# Writing Monad and Traversable instances for NonEmpty

Tags: haskell

I have a problem with instances definitions. I cannot make definition complies the identity law in monad and traverse instances. Here the type:

```
data NotEmpty a = LastValue a | MidValue a (NotEmpty a) deriving Show
instance Functor NotEmpty where
    fmap f (LastValue a) = LastValue (f a) 
    fmap f (MidValue a b) = MidValue (f a) (fmap f b)
instance Applicative NotEmpty where
    pure = LastValue
    (LastValue f) <*> LastValue a = LastValue (f a)
    (LastValue f) <*> MidValue a b = pure (f a) 
    (MidValue f x) <*> MidValue a b =  MidValue (f a) (x <> b)
    (MidValue f x) <*> LastValue a =  LastValue (f a)
instance Monad NotEmpty where
    (LastValue a) >>= f = f a
    (MidValue a b) >>= f = f a
instance Foldable NotEmpty where
    foldMap f (LastValue a) = f a
    foldMap f (MidValue a b) = (f a) <> (foldMap f b)
instance Traversable NotEmpty where
    traverse f (LastValue a) = fmap LastValue (f a)
    traverse f (MidValue a b) = traverse f b
```

I tried:

```
(MidValue a b) >>= f = MidValue a (b >>= f)
```

get error:

```
* Couldn't match type b' with a'
      b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          (>>=) :: forall a b. NotEmpty a -> (a -> NotEmpty b) -> NotEmpty b
        at LabWorks4.hs:87:19-21
      a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          (>>=) :: forall a b. NotEmpty a -> (a -> NotEmpty b) -> NotEmpty b
        at LabWorks4.hs:87:19-21
      Expected type: NotEmpty a
        Actual type: NotEmpty b
    * In the second argument of MidValue', namely (b >>= f)'
      In the expression: MidValue a (b >>= f)
      In an equation for `>>=':
          (MidValue a b) >>= f = MidValue a (b >>= f)
    * Relevant bindings include
        f :: a -> NotEmpty b (bound at LabWorks4.hs:88:24)
        b :: NotEmpty a (bound at LabWorks4.hs:88:17)
        a :: a (bound at LabWorks4.hs:88:15)
        (>>=) :: NotEmpty a -> (a -> NotEmpty b) -> NotEmpty b
          (bound at LabWorks4.hs:87:19)
   |
88 |     (MidValue a b) >>= f = MidValue a (b >>= f)
   |                                        ^^^^^^^
```

in traverse I tried:

```
traverse f (MidValue a b) = fmap (MidValue a) (traverse f b)
```

I get error:

```
 * Couldn't match type b' with a'
      b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          traverse :: forall (f :: * -> *) a b.
                      Applicative f =>
                      (a -> f b) -> NotEmpty a -> f (NotEmpty b)
        at LabWorks4.hs:134:5-12
      a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          traverse :: forall (f :: * -> *) a b.
                      Applicative f =>
                      (a -> f b) -> NotEmpty a -> f (NotEmpty b)
        at LabWorks4.hs:134:5-12
      Expected type: f (NotEmpty a)
        Actual type: f (NotEmpty b)
    * In the second argument of fmap', namely (traverse f b)'
      In the expression: fmap (MidValue a) (traverse f b)
      In an equation for `traverse':
          traverse f (MidValue a b) = fmap (MidValue a) (traverse f b)
    * Relevant bindings include
        b :: NotEmpty a (bound at LabWorks4.hs:135:28)
        a :: a (bound at LabWorks4.hs:135:26)
        f :: a -> f b (bound at LabWorks4.hs:135:14)
        traverse :: (a -> f b) -> NotEmpty a -> f (NotEmpty b)
          (bound at LabWorks4.hs:134:5)
    |
135 |     traverse f (MidValue a b) = fmap (MidValue a) (traverse f b)
```

Comment: @hnetfatl There is no error in code, but when I try to make definition wich complies the identity law, I just get infinite type error or rigid type variable error

Comment: The `traverse` implementation should be `MidValue <$> f a <*> traverse f b`. Similarly for `>>=`. You need to apply `f` to both the head and the tail.

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thank you.

Comment: @LambdaFairy Could you write full answer to the question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only applies `f` to the tail of the list. A correct implementation must apply `f` to both the head and the tail.

```
instance Monad NotEmpty where
    LastValue a >>= f = f a
    MidValue a b >>= f = f a <> (b >>= f)  -- assuming that NonEmpty is a Semigroup

instance Traversable NotEmpty where
    traverse f (LastValue a) = LastValue <$> f a
    traverse f (MidValue a b) = MidValue <$> f a <*> traverse f b
```

Note that `Functor`, `Foldable`, and `Traversable` can be automatically derived, so you don't need to write them yourself:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}

data NotEmpty a = LastValue a | MidValue a (NotEmpty a)
    deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the current `Applicative` instance, though law-abiding, is not consistent with the `Monad` instance given in this answer. If you are going to give a `Monad` instance, the `Applicative` instance should be changed to be the nondeterminism one rather than the zippy one.

Answer (score 3):

## Monad

Your attempt at the monad definition is incorrect.

```hs
(MidValue a b) >>= f = MidValue a (b >>= f)
```

Suppose your `MidValue a b` has type `NotEmpty Int`. This would mean `a` is of type `Int`, while `b` is of type `NotEmpty Int`. Now let's say that `f` is a function of type `Int -> NotEmpty String`. Following your definition, `b >>= f`  will be of type `NonEmpty String`. This means that in `MidValue a (b >>= f)`, `a` has type `Int`, while `(b >>= f)` has type `NonEmpty String`. It is therefore not possible to construct a valid type this way.

Instead, you should define a concatenation function. This can be done by defining an instance of `Semigroup` for `NotEmpty` as follows:

```
instance Semigroup (NotEmpty a) where
    LastValue a <> b   = MidValue a b
    MidValue a as <> b = MidValue a (as <> b)
```

Next, you can use `(<>)` in your `Monad` instance:

```
(MidValue a b) >>= f = f a <> (b >>= f)
```

## Traversable

Your attempt at this instance fails in a similar way to the monad instance.

```
traverse f (MidValue a b) = fmap (MidValue a) (traverse f b)
```

Here, `MidValue a` is of type `NotEmpty a -> NotEmpty a`. `traverse f b` is of type `Applicative f => f (NotEmpty b)`. These two types are impossible to unify with the type of `fmap`: `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

So, for `traverse f (MidValue a b)`, you already figured out you need to recursively call `traverse f` for `b`. You can do something very similar for `a` as you've done in the case of `LastValue`:

```
let a' = fmap pure (f a)
    b' = traverse f b
```

You now have two values with the same type: `Applicative f =>  f (NotEmpty b)`. The final step is to concatenate these two values  once again. The easiest way to do this is to make use of [liftA2](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2), for which you'll need to add `import Control.Applicative` to the top of your file. `liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c` can be used two combine two values that are both wrapped in some Applicative type by providing a function `a -> b -> c`. In this case, you can just supply the concatenation function that was defined earlier to `liftA2`. The final result of the case would be as follows:

```
traverse f (MidValue a b) = let a' = fmap pure (f a)
                                b' = traverse f b
                            in liftA2 (<>) a' b'
```